# C# webbrowser control - Confirm JavaScript function Executed and get response message

Tags: javascript, c#, browser, web, controls

I have a web browser control, I want to open a webpage and execute a JavaScript function that used `AJAX` to send the data and if data meet some rules it send back a `<div ...`.
The `<div` will display a message whether submit succeed or not.
I want to check if data sent and stored successfully then Invoke another JavaScript function.

But now I am using web browser [`DocumentCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event handler to find out page has been loaded and so on ...

I have to use that event handler.

What should I do to confirm JavaScript function executed and the response message is success?

Comment: Do you have control on the html content or does it come from a 3rd site?

Comment: It comes from a 3rd site.

Comment: Then you are in trouble, there is not a standard way to do it. You should use some hacks like injecting some js code to your html etc.

Comment: thank you for your reply, can you give me an example of that?